# Host .Net Core 6 application on CPanel

Tags: c#, .net-core, hosting, dedicated-hosting, cpanel-uapi

I need to host .Net Core 6 application on CPanel. The only solution I found is to install Nexucore in CPanel in suggested. But unfortunately NexusCore is not available anymore. Please suggest an alternative or a workoround to make it work.
Thank you.

a workaround to install Nesuxcore to CPanel or any alternative is preferred.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.